# in app billing i get response in response handler class so how I check it in activity?

Tags: android

i am facing problem since two day, i get response RESULT_OK but how can i check it into activity. after this i have to go to download window function, it is not showing dialog.please help me out thanks in advance...:(

```
ResponseHandler rep = new ResponseHandler();      
String ecase=rep.responsecheck;   
rep.register(mDungeonsPurchaseObserver);
   System.out.println(ecase);
   if(ecase!=null){
   if(ecase.matches("RESULT_OK")){/        
   Toast.makeText(this,ecase, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }
   else{
       Toast.makeText(this,ecase, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }
   }else{
   Toast.makeText(this,ecase, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }`
```

but this working is in oncreate and get null.

Comment: Use the onActivityResult to get the response handle rather than ResponseHandler

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
     public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    switch (requestCode) 
       {
    case REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE:
        //Body what ever u want to do....
       }}
```

Comment: this is not working, and in handle class i got a response but giving an error Null pointer Exception